# How to use the scp command on two different servers without a password prompt?

Tags: ssh, openssh, scp

I am trying to transfer files from one server to another using the `scp` command without having to enter a password. To this end I generated key files and copied them to each server's `.ssh` folder; but when I run the `scp` command I still need to type the password for my other server.

I am using Cloudways servers; we can't edit `.ssh` files on those but I added the keys using their portal and they were added to `authorized_keys`.

I am using this command:

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -rv /home/00000000.cloudwaysapps.com/fdbbgbgbgb/public_html/Test1/test.html server2@000.000.00.00:/home/0000000.cloudwaysapps.com/bgbtrbgb/public_html/Test1
```

What do we need to do to automate transfers between two different servers? I already tried `ssh-keygen` but it didn't work on the servers. Locally I generated keys and added them to both servers manually, and with those I can log in to both servers without entering a password; I am only asked for a password when transferring files between the servers.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how I should configure the SSH keys of my second server on the first one?

Comment: explain how you are starting the script that fails. Using cron ? As root or a specific user ? Just guessing it's not finding the key-files!

Comment: Yes it is prompting password for second server where i am transferring file

Answer (score 1):

> From local i generated keys and added to both servers manually with that i can login in both servers without typing password it is only giving me password while transferring files.

When you copy a file between your local machine and a remote one, or login to it from your local machine, you can set up certificate-based authentication, and indeed you note that this already works. (At least, you explained that you can `ssh` without needing a password, and this is much the same thing.)

```
date >date.txt
scp date.txt remoteHostA:
scp date.txt remoteHostB:
```

However, what you are now doing is copying from `remoteHostA` to `remoteHostB` while logged in to `remoteHostA`. At that point `remoteHostA` is now the client and you need to treat it as such.

On `remoteHostA` you need to create ssh keys using something like `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and transfer and install the resulting public key to `remoteHostB` in much the same way that you did when installing the public key from your local computer.

Alternatively, you can transfer files from `remoteHostA` to `remoteHostB` via your local system, but you have to be logged into that and run the command from there for it to work:

```
scp -3v remoteHostA:date.txt remoteHostB:
```

(You only need the `-r` flag if you're copying a directory tree of files.)

Comment: thank you for your answer our problem is solved.
It is giving us password because we did it manually on cloudways server we can't .ssh files.
We gone to cloudways support and they added keys from their side after that problem is solved.

Comment: @Jay glad to hear the issue is solved. If this answer helped you please ✔ accept it